# app is crashing because of an Activity invokation

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to invoke an activity from the MainActivity via a button with OnClickListener

The first activity is responding and works, the second activity doesn't work and crashes the application

Please help me to find the solution

Thanks!!!

here is the code:

```
class Layout{
    public Layout(){

        btnStopWatch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStopWatch);
        btnTimer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTimer);
    }
    Button btnStopWatch, btnTimer;
}

class Event{
    public Event(){
        l.btnStopWatch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StopWatchActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        l.btnTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}

Layout l; Event e;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    l = new Layout(); e = new Event();
}}
```

First Activity that works:

public class StopWatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
class Layout{
    public Layout(){
        tvHours = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHours);
        tvMinutes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMinutes);
        tvSeconds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSeconds);
        tvBack = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvBack);

        btnStartStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStartStop);
        btnReset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
    }
    TextView tvHours, tvMinutes, tvSeconds, tvBack;
    Button btnStartStop, btnReset;
}

class Event{
    public Event(){
        l.btnStartStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isStarted){
                    Stop();
                }else {
                    Start();
                }
            }
        });
        l.btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Reset();
            }
        });
        l.tvBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}

Layout l; Event e;
boolean isStarted = false;
int sec = 0, min = 0, hour = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop_watch);

    l = new Layout(); e = new Event();
}

public void Start(){
    l.btnStartStop.setText("Stop");
    isStarted = true;
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isStarted){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(isStarted){
                                MoveTime();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }catch (InterruptedException e){

                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

public void MoveTime(){
    sec++;
    if (sec >= 59){
        sec = 0;
        min++;
        if(min >= 59){
            min = 0;
            hour++;
        }
    }
    UpdateScreen();
}

public void UpdateScreen(){
    l.tvHours.setText(Format(hour));
    l.tvMinutes.setText(Format(min));
    l.tvSeconds.setText(Format(sec));
}

public void CleanScreen(){
    l.tvHours.setText("00");
    l.tvMinutes.setText("00");
    l.tvSeconds.setText("00");
}

public String Format(int i){
    if (i<=9){
        return "0" + i;
    }else{
        return Integer.toString(i);
    }
}

public void Stop(){
    isStarted = false;
    l.btnStartStop.setText("Start");
}

public void Reset(){
    if(isStarted)
        Stop();
    CleanScreen();
    sec = 0;
    min = 0;
    hour = 0;

}}
```

second activity that doesn't work:

public class TimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
class Layout {
    public Layout() {
        etHour = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHour);
        etHour.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax("0", "24")});
        etMin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMin);
        etMin.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax("0", "59")});
        etSec = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSec);
        etSec.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax("0", "59")});

        btnStartStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartStop);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);

        tvBack1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvBack);
    }
    EditText etHour, etMin, etSec;
    Button btnStartStop, btnReset;
    TextView tvBack1;
}

class Event {
    public Event() {
        l.btnStartStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isStarted) {
                    Stop();
                } else {
                    Start();
                }
            }
        });
        l.btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Reset();
            }
        });
        l.tvBack1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}

Layout l;
Event e;
boolean isStarted = false;
int sec = 0, min = 0, hour = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);

    l = new Layout();
    e = new Event();
}

public void Start() {
    l.btnStartStop.setText("Stop");
    isStarted = true;
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isStarted) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (isStarted) {
                                MoveTime();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

public void MoveTime() {
    sec = Integer.valueOf(l.etSec.getText().toString());
    min = Integer.valueOf(l.etMin.getText().toString());
    hour = Integer.valueOf(l.etHour.getText().toString());
    sec--;
    if (sec < 0) {
        sec = 59;
        min--;
        if (min < 0) {
            min = 59;
            hour--;
        }
    }
    UpdateScreen();
    if (hour == 0) {
        if (min == 0) {
            if (sec == 0) {
                Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void UpdateScreen(){
    l.etHour.setText(Format(hour));
    l.etMin.setText(Format(min));
    l.etSec.setText(Format(sec));
}

public void CleanScreen(){
    l.etHour.setText("00");
    l.etMin.setText("00");
    l.etSec.setText("00");
}

public String Format(int i){
    if (i<=9){
        return "0" + i;
    }else{
        return Integer.toString(i);
    }
}

public void Stop(){
    isStarted = false;
    l.btnStartStop.setText("Start");
}

public void Reset(){
    if(isStarted)
        Stop();
    CleanScreen();
    sec = 0;
    min = 0;
    hour = 0;
}}
```

Comment: `Rocket Android Programming` you're doing.

Comment: Can you please add the log?

Comment: Why unnecessary classes?

Comment: replace `getApplicationContext()` with `Activity.this` and check whether you have declared your activities in the `Manifest`.Adding your logcat output to the question  can be more helpful

Comment: This is the log:E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                             Process: com.example.gatlan.clocks, PID: 3024
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gatlan.clocks/com.example.gatlan.clocks.TimerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference